# Why does this yield different values on using sizeof operator?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    int * p = new int(40);  // here `p` points to an array having space for 40 ints or space allocated is 40 bytes?
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        cin>>p[i];
    cout<<sizeof(p)<<"\n";   // here, the output should be size of array since p points to an array
    int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}; // since, here it will output 20 (space allocated for the entire array)
    cout<<sizeof(arr)<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

So, I have two questions (the first two comments in the program)

1. Here `p` points to an array having space for 40 ints or space allocated is 40 bytes?
2. Here, the output should be size of array since `p` points to an array because technically speaking, `arr` is also a pointer and when we do `*arr` it references to the first element of the array.

Comment: `p` is a pointer. `arr` is an array. Plenty of duplicates out there.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `p` is defined as a pointer, so `sizeof(p)` is the same as `sizeof(int*)`, with is 4 on 32bit systems and 8 on 64bit systems.

In the second case, `arr` is a static array, so `sizeof(arr)` is the same as `sizeof(int[5])` which returns `5*sizeof(int)`, assuming there's no padding or other complex work happening "under the hood".

Note that when you pass an array name as an argument to a function which accepts a pointer as a formal function parameter, the array "decays" to a pointer, so calling `sizeof` on an argument yields behavior you likely did not expect. For example:

---

**Code Listing**

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printSize(int* arg);

int main(void)
{
    int *p;
    int arr[10];
    printf("sizeof p:%d\n", sizeof(p));
    printf("sizeof arr:%d\n", sizeof(arr));
    printSize(p);
    printSize(arr);

    return 0;
}

void printSize(int* arg)
{
    printf("sizeof arg:%d\n", sizeof(arg));
}
```

---

**Sample Output**

---

```
sizeof p:8
sizeof arr:40
sizeof arg:8
sizeof arg:8
```

Comment: If the array is accepted by reference then it doesn't decay, and it basically works as it should.

Comment: "decay" is irrelevant. The function parameter is a pointer. It doesn't matter *what* happens to whatever is passed as argument.

Answer (score 3):

When you say `int *p = new int(40);` you are actually allocating space for a *single* integer and filling that space with the integer `40`. If you want an array of 40 integers, you should use square brackets:

```
int *p = new int[40];
```

So, to answer question #1: neither. The space allocated is the size of one `int` on your system.

To answer question #2: the first line of output is the size of a single pointer on your system (because `p` is just a pointer). This will probably be the same as the size of an `int`, which is likely 4 bytes. The second line of output will be the total allocation size of your array of integers, so it will be `40*sizeof(int)`, or `160`.

Answer (score 1):

Your two uses of `sizeof` are querying the size of the types `int*` and `int[5]` respectively.

(also, you have a bug and meant `new int[40]`, not `new int(40)`, but that doesn't affect the results of `sizeof`)